# Intero always installs isolated GHC

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, intero

I opened a Haskell file on a fresh installation of Emacs & Intero. While booting up, intero is trying to install an isolated GHC. This even though my project has `stack.yaml` which has `system-ghc: true`. Running `stack install` in this directory does `not` reinstall GHC.

Is there any way to make Intero use system ghc instead of reinstalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emacs mode is probably trying to install the `intero` binary outside the context of your project, to ensure that the `intero` binary isn't affected by the project's library choices. I'm guessing that setting `system-ghc: true` in your user config file (`~/.stack/config.yaml`) instead will solve this problem.

You may also want to set `install-ghc: false` to disable automatic GHC installation.

Comment: Setting these options in `~/.stack/config.yaml` worked. Thanks!